# How to start a background process in gnome-terminal automatically at the start

Tags: gnome-terminal, background-process

I want to start a background process (tail [a log file]) in each gnome-terminal automatically when the terminal is created.
I've tried
`gnome-terminal -e "tail -f /var/log/syslog &"`
which starts the tail, but in the foreground and it takes over the terminal completely. `CTRL+Z` has no effect. Is it possible?

Comment: Read `man journalctl`, do `sudo journalctl  --follow`.

Comment: @waltinator Thank you, but I don't see how that relates to my problem...

Comment: @waltinator I'm looking for a general solution to starting background processes automatically, not just a syslog solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was trivial: just add it to .bashrc